# argv problem, new to c

Tags: c

I am having trouble with argv.

```
meltcheck(argv[1]);
```

function:

```
int meltcheck(char a[])
{
        if(a != "a" && a != NULL)
        {
                char dir[600];
                strcpy(dir, "del ");
                strncat(dir, a, sizeof(a));
                dir[strlen(dir)] = '\0';
                printf("\ndtmeltcheck: %s\n", dir);
                //system(dir);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Sorry the code got all messed up when I tried to paste it.  But the problem is that argv is only storing 4 characters, even if the string is > 4 characters.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Don't use the `<code>` tag, click the button that looks like `{}`, or just indent all code by four spaces.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems here. First off, you cannot compare the contents of strings using `==` or `!=` in C - that compares the pointer values, so `a != "a"` will always be TRUE. Also, `dir[strlen(dir)]` is always equal to `'\0'` by definition. And `sizeof(a)` is the size of a `char *` (i.e. 4), not the length of the data.

Your function should look something like this:

```
int meltcheck( char *a )
{
    if( a != NULL && strcmp( a, "a" ) != 0 ) {
        char dir[600];
        strcpy( dir, "del " );
        strcat( dir, a );
        printf( "\ndtmeltcheck: %s\n", dir );
        // system( dir );
        // note that you should be using the unlink() function here
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `strncat` does append a NULL character.  At least according to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncat.html

Comment: @Nick: You're right, thanks. I was thinking of `strncpy`. I will update my answer.

Comment: You should say explicitly why you reversed the order of the comparisons (value equality versus pointer NULLness). That is, you are using the short-circuiting of the `&&` operator to protect against an undefined dereference.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `sizeof` in this way on arrays passed as parameters to functions.

The reason is that when passing an array to a function in C, the array decays into a pointer to its first element.  As a result, when you take `sizeof(a)`, you get the size of the pointer, not the size of the array.  In this case, it is the same as `sizeof(char *)`, which on a 32-bit machine will be 4, as you observe.

You're also using `strncat` in a way it wasn't really intended, though.  The point of the third parameter is to prevent a buffer overflow if `strlen(a)` is longer than the amount of space in the buffer you're copying into, in this case, `dir`.  I think what you want is:

```
strncat(dir, a, 595); /** 600 - "dir " - \0 = 595 */
```

Because there is room for 595 more characters in `dir`.

Also note that you can't compare C strings using `!=`.  Your `if` statement should use `strcmp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that sizeof(a) will return sizeof(char*) (the size of a poitner to a character) rather than the length of the character string a.
So it is only copying four characters.

Comment: Thanks so much, sorry I have been overlooking things like this all day, I haven't programmed in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Use strlen instead of sizeof. Sizeof of a pointer will be 4 on a 32 bits platform.